# Android: Continuously seek for a specific WIFI Connection since boot completed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

How can I check if a specific wifi connection is availible say for example SSID: `Saaram01` is available. Whenever it is available I get notified.

I have done all this work through a button, like if you click the button it notifies if `Saaram01` is available overwise does nothing.

The problem or the question basically is how can I check for this SSID availability everything 24/7.. Obviously for this I cant use a background service.. So is there anyother possible way to do it ?? Like using broadcast reciever or anything else ?

Any help will be highly appreciated ! 
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

```
IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
i.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ScanWiFiActivity a = ScanWiFiActivity.instance();
        WifiManager w = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        List<ScanResult> l = w.getScanResults();
        a.Clear();
        for (ScanResult r : l) {

            if(r.SSID.equals("saaram01") {
               //Perform your logic here
              }
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(receiver, i);
```

n the FOR block work your magic and take action when you identify your network by SSID or BSSID

Comment: What do you mean by wifi connection is established or changed ? I didnt get you.. What I want is If wifi is enabled then it checks detects automatically whenever `Saaram01` is available ? So whats the purpose of connection state changing here ?